# How do I print array within array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to echo some values within two arrays . I have a variable called: $listDigitalDownloads

When I var_dump($listDigitalDownloads);

I get:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["digital_downloads_title"]=>
    string(5) "Title"
    ["digital_downloads_image"]=>
    string(7) "url.com"
    ["digital_downloads_author"]=>
    string(6) "Author"
    ["digital_download_files"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["digital_download_file_type"]=>
        string(11) "File Type 1"
        ["digital_download_file"]=>
        string(7) "url.pdf"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["digital_download_file_type"]=>
        string(11) "File Type 2"
        ["digital_download_file"]=>
        string(7) "url.pdf"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["digital_download_file_type"]=>
        string(11) "File Type 3"
        ["digital_download_file"]=>
        string(7) "url.pdf"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to echo ["digital_download_file_type"] and ["digital_download_file"] using a foreach loop.

But when I var_dump ($listDigitalDownloadFiles); I just receive:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "digital_download_files"
}
```

I have tried:

```
foreach($listDigitalDownloadZero as $listDigitalDownloadFile) {
    $type = $listDigitalDownloadFile['digital_download_file_type'];
    echo $type;
}
```

But do not get any results.

Any help would be great

Here is my full code:

```
$listDigitalDownloads = get_field('digital_downloads_incentives'); 
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($listDigitalDownloads);
echo '</pre>';

foreach($listDigitalDownloads as $listDigitalDownload) {
    $title = $listDigitalDownload['digital_downloads_title'];
    $author = $listDigitalDownload['digital_downloads_author'];
    $image = $listDigitalDownload['digital_downloads_image'];
    $listDigitalDownloadFiles = ['digital_download_files'];
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump ($listDigitalDownloadFiles);
    echo '</pre>';
    foreach($listDigitalDownloadZero as $listDigitalDownloadFile) {
        $type = $listDigitalDownloadFile['digital_download_file_type'];
        echo $type;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to echo the value of ['digital_download_file_type']

Comment: Include your array PHP format

Comment: I added echo '<pre>'; - which is how I formatted that var_dump. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Post the PHP array which you have in your code

Comment: The field(s) are generated from Advanced Custom Fields Wordpress Plugin and that is all the code I have on that page.

Comment: where does `$listDigitalDownloadZero` come from? It's undefined. Don't you want to do: `foreach($listDigitalDownloadFiles as $listDigitalDownloadFile) {`

Comment: What's the point of the variable `$listDigitalDownloadFiles`? It's an array containing the same literal string each time through the loop, it's not anything related to the data.

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned the variable `$listDigitalDownloadZero`. You need:

```
$listDigitalDownloadZero = $listDigitalDownload['digital_download_files'];
```

I suspect you actually intended to assign this to `$listDigitalDownloadFiles`, but you just assigned a literal array containing the same string each time, rather than indexing `$listDigitalDownload`.

Comment: That was it! I meant for that variable to be:
```$listDigitalDownloadFiles = $listDigitalDownload['digital_download_files'];```
And then set:
```
foreach($listDigitalDownloadFiles as $listDigitalDownloadFile) {
                $type = $listDigitalDownloadFile['digital_download_file_type'];
                echo $type;
              }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just needed another set of eyes to see that!